# Jest Mock Several Components at one go

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I would like to do something like

```
[
  { path: 'path1', comp: () => <div>comp 1</div> },
  { path: 'path2', comp: () => <div>comp 2</div> },
].forEach(({ path, comp }) => {
  jest.mock(path, {
    __esModule: true,
    default: comp
  })
});
```

But I get the following error: `The module factory of 'jest.mock()' is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.`

Any idea on how to do that ?

I have tried with a simple for loop as well but I get the same error.

Comment: Note: In order to mock properly, Jest needs `jest.mock('moduleName')` to be in the same scope as the require/import statement. Try to use `for` loop instead of `forEach` method and make the array name start with *mock*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jest.mock` is really tricky thing since it should be executed before any `import` actually run. So there are [some limitations](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks):

> A limitation with the factory parameter is that, since calls to jest.mock() are hoisted to the top of the file, it's not possible to first define a variable and then use it in the factory. An exception is made for variables that start with the word 'mock'. It's up to you to guarantee that they will be initialized on time!

I don't know why, even after renaming `comp` to `mockComp` code was failing till I removed `__esmodule: true`. So this passed to me:

```
[
  { path: 'comp1', mockComp: () => <div>1</div> },
  { path: 'comp2', mockComp: () => <span>2</span> },
].forEach(({ path, mockComp }) => {
  jest.mock(path, () => mockComp);
});
```

Anyway, even if you find way module to be `esModule` and code was passed, I still believe that having separate `jest.mock()` per each module is better maintainable than iteration over config. At least it's really easy to add, delete and mix inline mocks alongside automocks `jest.mock('module1');` that relies on code in `__mocks__` folder(unlike approach with `forEach` and config object)

Comment: Yes the part where jest.mock() calls are hoisted so that they appear before the imports makes sense. Thats the part I was missing. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can create a mock component

**`__mocks__/dummyComponent.jsx`**

```
export default () => <div>comp 1</div>;
```

and then use jest's [moduleNameMapper configuration](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string)

**`package.json`**

```
{
  // ...
  "jest": {
     "moduleNameMapper": {
       "path1|path2$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/dummyComponent.jsx"
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: The thing is all these paths will need to return a different component. How would you achieve that ?